# Getting a reference to a CloudFileDirectory in Azure Automation and PowerShell Runbooks

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I'm working with Azure Automation and PowerShell Runbooks and I need to get a reference
to a CloudFileDirectory.  The directory already exists, and does not need to be created.  The only way that I have found to create this reference is to using New-AzStorageDirectory.  This looks like it will create the Directory.  If this is the only way, how do I call this function to get the CloudFileDirectory?  If there is another way please let me know the syntax to call the necessary function.

Comment: Maybe try [example 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragefile?view=azps-7.1.0#example-1--list-directories-in-a-share) ?  `Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName "MyShareName" | Where {$_.GetType().Name -eq "AzureStorageFileDirectory"}`. Yep. strange there is a `Get-AzStorageFile` cmdlet but no `Get-AzStorageDirectory` equivalent..

Comment: Very close.  After poking around it looks like you can do something like this:  (Get-AzStorageFile -Context $SourceContext  -ShareName "fileshare" -Path "9999").CloudFileDirectory